# CSS div style sheet not reflecting in html

Tags: html, css

Trying to style a div tag. Here is my code. I've gone over it numerous times and can't figure it out. My other style elements work perfect on the page but I can't seem to get **.header** to work.

resume.html

```css
body {
  font-family:serif;
  font-size: 83%
}
h1 {
  border-style: double;
  color: #bb6938;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  color: #bb6938;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 100%
}
h3 {
  color: #bb6938;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
li {
  font-style: italic;
}
p{
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #006747;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <center>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Resume</h1>
            <h2>Julia</h2>
            <br>
            <img src="julia.jpg" />
        </div>
    </center>
   </body>

</html>
```

Tried to make sure all my brackets were there and everything was closed properly. I just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: you have a `<body style="background-color:#eed9c4">` tag inside your `head` tag

Comment: "and everything was closed properly". You missed the `;` at the end of your first `.header`rule, after `blue`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a large amount of errors, both in your HTML and your CSS. It is good practice to also not use deprecated `HTML elements` like `center` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center.
Use your stylesheet for positioning text. I've updated your HTML and CSS to achieve what I believe you may be looking for. I've added only the `div` HTML. Also, remove the `body` line inside your `head`, I've also added the background color style to the CSS.
**Please note, that the background color you've chosen for the `body` of the HTML is not showing because there is only 1 `div` with a `background-color` of blue. If you add more content outside of that header `div` the almond color will show up.

```css
body {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 83%;
  background-color: #eed9c4;
}

h1 {
  border-style: double;
  color: #bb6938;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #bb6938;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h3 {
  color: #bb6938;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

li {
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #006747;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
      <h1>Resume</h1>
      <h2>Julia</h2>
      <br>
      <img src="julia.jpg" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brent. I am a beginner HTML coder and am currently taking a beginner class in college. My professor is practically useless and has been a terrible teacher. For example, he told us to use <center> even with CSS if that tells you anything.